# Doctest with datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, doctest

I have done a search but could not find what I was after.

My code is as followed:

```
import datetime
import doctest
import os


def parseOptions():

    import optparse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage= '-h')
    parser.add_option('-d', '--difference', \
                      type= 'int')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    return options

now = datetime.datetime.now()
subtract = datetime.timedelta(days=10, hours=11)
difference = now - subtract

def checktime(now - b):
    """Returns a - b

    >>> checktime(now - 10)
    'now - 10'

    >>> checktime(now - 20)
    'now - 20'

    >>> checktime(now - 30)
    'now - 30'
    """
    return now - b

if__name__== "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()


print
print 'The time now is =', now.strftime("%I:%M:%S%p %a, %B %d %Y")
print 'The time minus the difference =', difference.strftime("%I:%M:%S%p %a, %B %d %Y")
print
```

I want the doctest to test that the time now minus the number (10, 20, 30 in hours) is giving the correct output before proceeding.

When I run the script in command prompt I get the following mesage:

```
2 items had no tests:
    time
    time.struct_time
0 tests in 2 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

I have attempted to changes bits and pieces to find what is being defined with time and time.struct_time and have failed miserably.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, make sure your code has no syntax errors. The posted script does not run.

Comment: If the doctest section of the code is removed the script runs without issue. So it I must not be doing something properly there.

Comment: Surely there was a error about "chectime" not being defined

Comment: Sorry, I picked that up when running the script again and forgot to edit here.

Comment: For example `def checktime(now - b)`. There is no `b` found anywhere else in the global name space. You likely ment `def checktime(now, b)`.

Comment: What is your goal with this? It's impossible to figure out from your code, because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It is a small part of a larger piece I am working on. For the time being I was just after a way to doctest time. It is nice and easy with integers and strings, but something like this was a bit out of my league. Thankfully others are more adept at this then I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctest is useful if you want to test that the function is doing what was *intended*. In your case, I presume you want to subtract `b` hours from the `datetime` argument and return the difference.

Re-writing your function to `subtime`

```
def subtime(a,b):
    subtract = datetime.timedelta(hours=b)
    difference = a - subtract
    return difference
```

To run doctests, you'll need to provide some sample calling values and the expected results. Think about the corner cases for your function (Places where something *wierd* might happen). Now let us form some test-cases

1. Subtract less than 24 hours
2. Subtract exactly 24 hours
3. Subtract more than 24 hours
4. Subtract 0 hours
5. Add some hours (-ve arguments)

Now write down how the function will be called in each case. Use the same `datetime` as first argument for simplicity. (Do not use script variables such as `now` because you cannot predict their values when the script runs)

1. `subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),10)`
2. `subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),24)`
3. `subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),30)`
4. `subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),0)`
5. `subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),-5)`

Now calculate (using a pen and paper) what should be the ideal result for each case

1. `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 1, 0)`
2. `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10, 11, 0)`
3. `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10, 5, 0)`
4. `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 11, 0)`
5. `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 16, 0)`

Add this to your function in the documentation string `""" """`

```
def subtime(a,b):
    """ (datetime,int) -> datetime 
    Subtract b hours from a datetime.datetime and return the new datetime object

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),10)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 1, 0)

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),24)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10, 11, 0)

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),30)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10, 5, 0)

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),0)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 11, 0)

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),-5)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 16, 0)

    """
    subtract = datetime.timedelta(hours=b)
    difference = now - subtract
    return difference
```

Your script now is

```
import datetime
import doctest
import os

def parseOptions():

    import optparse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage= '-h')
    parser.add_option('-d', '--difference', \
                      type= 'int')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    return options
now = datetime.datetime.now()

def subtime(a,b):
    """ (datetime,int) -> datetime 
    Subtract b hours from a datetime.datetime and return the new datetime object

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),10)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 1, 0)

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),24)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10, 11, 0)

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),30)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10, 5, 0)

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),0)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 11, 0)

    >>> subtime(datetime.datetime(2013,11,11,11,0),-5)
    datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 16, 0)

    """
    subtract = datetime.timedelta(hours=b)
    difference = a - subtract
    return difference

if __name__== "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()    

print
print 'This is the time now -', now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p %a, %B %d %Y")
difference=subtime(now,10)
print 'This is the time minus the difference -', difference.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p %a, %B %d %Y")
print
```

And the output

```
$ python try.py 

This is the time now - 02:40:57 PM Tue, May 28 2013
This is the time minus the difference - 04:40:57 AM Tue, May 28 2013
```

Note that with doctest you won't get *any* test related output if all the tests pass. (Everything is OK)

Comment: +1 This is perfect. Thank you so much. You have clearly and concisely pointed out my issue and taught me the correct way of answering the problem. If I could upvote this any more I would. Thank you again, you are a much better tutor than anything online! Thanks!

Comment: @Mitchell No Problem. Since you have started using `doctests`, I would recommend that you also look into `unittest`. The problem with doctests is that you can only test return values and even minor formatting problems can cause a test to fail. (As an example try removing the spaces from datetime in docstrings). `unittest` will allow you to write much more complicated tests (Like testing specific attributes of the returned objects)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a play around with `unittest` module and see if I can do the above test with the same if not similar results.